# accumulated totals of data in grafana / influx

Tags: influxdb, grafana

I've got a requirement to report on jira status information - and I'm not sure how to approach it.

Each issue has a status, and this status can change to any number of values.

What I want to be able to determine is how many issues where at any particular status at any particular time.

Previously, we had a system that polled for changes, and when one was detected, it recalculated totals. This is obviously very old-hat and inefficient.

Another approach is to intercept when a status changes, get the before value. post a `-1` to the `before` key. Then post a `+1` to the new key

If you then read over the data starting at the beginning and added up the + and -, you can get a count at any point in time. This is also obviously very old-hat and inefficient.

I was thinking that perhaps grafana / influx could handle this - however, I just can't seem to get it to work.

It must be something to do with aggregates or accumulations .

Has anyone done something similar and is willing to share ?

Edit: gentle *bump* : has anyone got some clues ?